# PHP composer require command with repositories details

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

I have below content in my composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/class-loader": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "2.3.*",
        "liip/drupal-testing": "dev-master",
    }
}
```

This project has been in production for a while and I want to add a new package (dejanb/stomp-php) without updating any of the existing packages. Executing below command adds the new packages and made necessary changes to autoloader, composer.json and composer.lock files.

```
composer require --prefer-dist "fusesource/stomp-php:2.1.*"
```

All good so far. Now found the the new packages I added doesn't provide all my requirements and I would need to apply my patch on top of it. So I forked it and committed changes.

Now I can do https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository to update my fork in composer.json and run composer update. However It updates all the the packages in composer.json.

Is there a way/command to add my new fork without update existing packages?

Comment: Why are you using "2.3.*" instead of "2.3.1" for example?

Comment: It's been there. I can't add/change it now.

Comment: Look here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update

Comment: I believe that if you run

`php composer.phar update vendor/package vendor/package2`

It will only update the vendor you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the command

```
php composer.phar update vendor/package vendor/package2
```

It will only update those packages. Therefore, if you run:

```
php composer.phar update dejanb/stomp-php
```

You should be good.